About the time it takes to change file permissions
I am considering changing the folder permissions on a NAS running on Windows from read-only for everyone to writable. The file count is 400,000 and the data size is 6TB. How long do you think the permission change will take? Additionally, if anyone has experience changing permissions with a similar setup, I would like to know how long it took. Thank you.

What is the throughput between where the command is executed and the storage. 1 GB? 10 GB?

I plan to perform the permission change through the local GUI on Windows. Are you referring to the data transfer rate in terms of HDD throughput?

I'm asking what is the speed of the network to the storage.
